# Stored procedure converts int to decimal

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, return-value

I am writing a stored procedure to return some stats. I have two different tables, one with stats collected after the system has been taken into use, another with stats since

My procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getStats(IN uID INT, IN since_date DateTime)
BEGIN
  DECLARE rowcount int;
  select klubid from core_medlemmer where id = uID into @klubid;
  select create_date from core_klub where id = @klubid into @create_date;

  if since_date < @create_date then
    -- select from historic and current
    select sum(attendance) from core_historic_modestatistik where medlemsid = uID into @historic_total;
    SELECT @historic_total + count(*) as total_attendance from core_fremmode where medlemsid= uID and dato >= since_date;
  else 
    -- select only current
    SELECT count(*) as total_attendance from core_fremmode where medlemsid= uID and dato >= since_date;
  end if;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Executing this stored procedure with `select sum(attendance) from core_historic_modestatistik where medlemsid = uID` looks correct:

```
+-----------------+
| sum(attendance) |
+-----------------+
|             655 | 
+-----------------+
```

But it appears that the addition converts it to a real:

```
+------------------------------------+
| total_attendance                   |
+------------------------------------+
| 656.000000000000000000000000000000 |
+------------------------------------+
```

The column i am summing is an int and the `count()` function should only be able to return `INT`s, so any tips as to why this is happening, and how to address itbest would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the best way to force types in select's in stored procs is to INSERT...SELECT into a temporary table (created in the proc with the desired types), and then select from that. You can try `CAST(x AS SIGNED)`, but then you can't control BIGINT, INT, etc..

Edit: The CAST is usually fine within a stored procedure/query; but when you need more defined types for interaction with API calls, such as `GetInt32(fieldnum)`, the temp table method can be very helpful.